# Defining an int with "if' statements using another "int" as a parameter

Tags: c++, if-statement, return

Trying to make an input-dependant variable with an int by changing it's values with if statements. Probably doing a dumb mistake, but so far, can't figure it out (As a side note, also tried with a Switch statement, couldn't make it work either).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
        
        int main(){
            
            int jobID;
            std::cin >> jobID;

            int setjobSalary (int jobSalary) {
                
                if (jobID == 1) {
                    
                    setjobSalary = 600;
                    
                    }
                
                else if (jobID == 2) {
                    
                    setjobSalary = 1600;
                    
                    }
                
                    return jobSalary;
                }
                
            int currentjobSalary = jobSalary - 300;
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've seen the error message from the compiler? `main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:46: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token` Functions cannot be defined inside of other functions (unless they're lambda functions). Not to mention you never call the `setjobSalary()` funtion and it should `return` the value. `setjobSalary = 600;` is wrong. c++ isn't the same as Basic.

Comment: You can't define a second function `setjobSalary` inside the body of `main` like that.

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not allow you to define a function inside of another function.  For what you are attempting to do, you don't need a function at all, just a variable, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
                        
int main()
{
    int jobID;
    std::cin >> jobID;

    int jobSalary;
                
    if (jobID == 1) {
        jobSalary = 600;
    }
    else if (jobID == 2) {
        jobSalary = 1600;
    }
    else {
        jobSalary = 0;
    }
                
    int currentjobSalary = jobSalary - 300;
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to define a function, it needs to be outside of `main()`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
        
int getjobSalary (int jobID)
{
    if (jobID == 1) {
        return 600;
    }
    else if (jobID == 2) {
        return 1600;
    }                    
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
                
int main()
{
    int jobID;
    std::cin >> jobID;

    int currentjobSalary = getJobSalary(jobID) - 300;
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can use a lambda (C++11 and later only), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
                        
int main()
{
    int jobID;
    std::cin >> jobID;

    auto getjobSalary = [=]() -> int {
        if (jobID == 1) {
            return 600;
        }
        else if (jobID == 2) {
            return 1600;
        }                    
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    int currentjobSalary = getJobSalary() - 300;
    ...

    return 0;
}
```